# Desktop Picture Placement

Tags: desktop, applescript, plist

I made an Automator app that changes the desktop picture to whatever image file you drop on its icon. It used to work perfectly until Snow Leopard. Now the image placement always resets to Full Screen, regardless of what it was previously set to.

Is there a way to change the default setting of the `desktop.plist` template? (I use "Centered" for my purposes)?

If not, I could sure use an Applescript that would reset the `desktop.plist` placement to "Centered" and then refresh the desktop to the new settings.